# SQL Server 2008 R2 Express refuses to save records

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-express

I have created a procedure to import all records from a Microsoft Access database into SQL Server 2008 R2 Express server. The SQL server sits behind a WCF service with EntityFramework 4. My MS Access database contains ~500 000 records, however only ~100 000 is written. EntityFramework doesn't throw any exception whatsoever, it just works and works, as if everything was OK. I thought this was an issue with SQL db not growing automatically since it said that "space left" was less than 1 MB. however I increased the DB size manually and the issue still remains. SQL Server ignores my writes?

Comment: Does your WCF service have any logging? Do you see it attempting to write all 500K records? That is: is it actually a SQL problem at all? Does your WCF service see any exceptions, or does it quietly swallow them?

Comment: @RogerLipscombe there is no exception whatsoever. As if everything is OK. I wrote the code so any exception is thrown back at the client. WCF tracing was off though, right now I am turning it on and trying again. (for the 4th time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do I always have to find an answer myself, but only after I ask somebody else? ... Turns out my assumption that MS access database primary key is unique, was bad. EF indeed makes 500k calls and oll of them succeed, but my logic includes code which checks for existence of PK from MS Access and if exists, updates it. So it most likely did 100k adds and 400k updates.